# Bicep: Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview Exception: Invalid value given for parameter ExternalAdministratorLoginName

Tags: azure-bicep

By bicep I'm trying to deploy a SQL Server to Azure.

The bicepcode what we are using is:

```
resource sqlServerResource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlserverServerName
  location: location
  properties: {
    version: '12.0'
    administratorLogin: sqlserverAdminName
    administratorLoginPassword: sqlserverAdminPassword
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'  
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: databaseAdminsGroupName
      sid: databaseAdminsGroupId
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: false      
    }
  }
}
```

This result in an error

> Invalid value given for parameter ExternalAdministratorLoginName. Specify a valid parameter value

Replacing the login AND sid with a string (not parameter) it will deploy?

```
 login: 'xxxxxxxx'
 sid: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

I'm passing a string. Looks like that when it's once set to an other AD user and I want to "reset" it fails . When using it from scratch it works fine.

Reproduce:

- Create bicep file
- Create powershell with the command:

  ```
   az deployment group create `
     --name $resourceGroupName `
     --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
     --template-file test.bicep `
     --parameters sqlserverServerName='issue20230912' `
                 location='westeurope' `
                 administratorLogin='SqlAdminLogin' `
                 administratorLoginPassword=$sqlserverAdminPassword `
                 databaseAdminsGroupId='xxxxx' `
                 databaseAdminsGroupName='xxxxx'
  ```
- Run it => Ok
- In the portal change the administartor group and save it. => Ok
- Run the powershell again: => FAIL

Comment: Login should be the group display name and Sid should be the objectid.

Comment: What is the value you are passing?

Comment: If the parameter is of type string. This should Work

Comment: I'm passing a string.
I have to be a little more specific. Looks like that when it's once set to an other AD user and I want to "reset"  it fails .
When using it from scratch it works

Comment: so you still have the issue ?

Comment: Depending on it. We are running these bicep files in the deployment pipeline to sync the  azure resources. Meaning when there is a need to change the administrators group we can't do it this way

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#serverexternaladministrator) and thanks to @Thomas for pointing in the right path, under server external administrator properties, `login` name must be a `group` name for which you are trying to assign it as a `sql administrator` with `Azure AD`, and `sid` must be the `object ID` of that specific group.

*I tried to deploy a SQL server to achieve your requirement and was successful as shown.*

```bash
param sqlserverServerName string = uniqueString('sql', resourceGroup().id)
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param administratorLogin string
@secure()
param administratorLoginPassword string
resource sqlServerResource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlserverServerName
  location: location
  properties: {
    version: '12.0'
    administratorLogin: administratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'  
      principalType: 'Group'
      login: 'JH' //Group Name from Azure AD
      sid: 'group object ID'
      tenantId: subscription().tenantId
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: false      
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Portal View:***

[image]

Comment: Correct this works. But when you you set it to manually something else and re-run the script then it fails

Comment: I set the values manually and tried the above deployment. It was successful. Can you brief me more about the issue. @Bart

Comment: Stange is that deploying to the existing sql server. Even when you set it a different AD user?

Comment: You need to change the `principalType`  to `user` if you want to try out with a user principal. @Bart

Comment: And changing to another group name and ID also worked for me without any errors. @Bart

Comment: I have no clue why it is working at your site. 
I also tested it at a different tenant.
- Create bicep file
- Create powershell with the command: 
 &az deployment group create
    --name $resourceGroupName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --template-file test.bicep `
    --parameters sqlserverServerName='issue20230912' ....
Run it => Ok
In the portal change the administartor group and save it. => Ok
Run the powershell again: => FAIL

Comment: Are you executing the same code which I've shared? @Bart

Comment: Is the above code works for you? @Bart

Comment: Yes i'm using the same ocde.
the only thing is that i'm executing it from the powershell
az deployment group create --name $rgName --resource-group $rgName -template-file test.bicep --parameters sqlserverServerName='issue20230912 etc...
=> Fail

Comment: Instead of passing parameters via command, try passing it in the code itself. Did you try that way? @Bart

Comment: Can you add all the parameters in a `json` file and pass it as a parameter file as shown in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-create-examples). @Bart

Comment: I tried every method. It does nt matter how you deliver the parameters.
For thr first time it works, after it has been resetted via the portal it won't work when you change it in the script to the  changed value it works again

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (confirmation and details of a workaround here): https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4988

In summary using 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators' child resource type instead of 'Microsoft.Sql/servers' property seems to fix the issue for some.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35681394)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I have added a little more detail.